# Increased CF JVM max heap size and now CF service will not start

Tags: windows, windows-xp, coldfusion

So I went in to ColdFusion Administrator and increased my CF JVM max heap size, then I was told I would need to restart the service, so I stopped the service, and then tried to start it again and got the following error message:

> Windows could not start the ColdFusion 8 Application Server on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 2.

So I went to the Event Viewer application, then took a look at the `Application` log and saw an error that said:

> The ColdFusion 8 Application Server service could not be started.  Check the server "coldfusion" log files for more information.

So I went to my ColdFusion `logs` directory  opened the `server.log` log file and I don't see anything useful in there or any of the other log files..

**Any idea how I can change the JVM heap size back to what it was so that I can start CF again?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be addressed in :
[Maximum JVM heap size greater than 1.8GB will prevent ColdFusion MX from starting](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/193/tn_19359.html)

> On 32-bit processor machines, the
>   largest contiguous memory address
>   space the operating system can
>   allocate to a process is 1.8GB.
>   Because of this, the maximum heap size
>   can only be set up to 1.8GB. On 64-bit
>   processor machines, the 1.8 GB limit
>   does not apply, as 64-bit processor
>   machines have a larger memory address
>   space.
>
> To correct this issue, the jvm.config
>   file must be modified:
>
> 1. Open the cf_root/runtime/bin/jvm.config file in
>      a text editor.
> 2. Locate the section labeled "# Arguments to VM".
> 3. Modify the `-Xmx` variable to set a maximum heap size less than 1.8GB.
>        For example: `-Xmx1024m`
> 4. Save the file.
> 5. Restart ColdFusion.

Be careful not too use a value that is too large for the computer. This may have a negative impact on the performance of Windows and on other installed products.